# How do I extract report data from MSAS and TM1 to Cognos?

Tags: sql-server, business-intelligence, cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-tm1

How do I extract report data from MSAS and TM1 to Cognos? (Cognos 10, but even Cognos 8)

I need to consolidate the data from two separate cubes: one from MSAS and another from TM1. I then need to extract it into a cognos report.

Can anyone help me? Even over skype chat/ gtalk? I would greatly appreciate it.

TIA!

Regards,
Maria

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: I although I would not recommend this, have you tried publishing those two different cube types in one package? My gut feel is that this won't work but I can't find any info to the contrary. Regardless, the 'proper' way to do this is go back to  the data sources that feed those cube and combine them properly in a database or another cube. It can be difficult combining data from multiple cubes of the same type let alone different types. I really think you should forget about combining this data up at the cube level.

Answer (score 0):

I have experience of creating a Datasource connection to MSAS cube in Cognos 8.4. Later versions of Congos BI even offer compatability with MSAS cubes.

There were some glitches like descriptions appearing member names and other member properties messed up. However we could do some Cognos reports out of that.

I would defenetly try creating a package with MSAS and TM1 cube as it is the only way to make data from different datasources meet on the same report. Name confomed dimentions same  to match them. Use Query Studio for test in principle, as at opens any datasource.